# Alernative to Neo4j Graph database

Tags: graph-databases, allegrograph

Looking for graph db which could be alternative for Neo4j, can any one suggest a better one which could be easily integrated with Java application and has better performance in migrating data from MSSQl to that graphdb.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at http://www.tinkerpop.com/ so that you could try lots of different graph implementations (Titan, Neo4j, OrientDB, Bitsy, etc.) prior to making your decision.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried http://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan - it's open source, free, supports data distribution.

Also OrientDB looks good.